# Contact Form 7 plugin email message body removed automatically

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am confused why the email body of contact form 7 wordpress plugin is removed or showing empty when my site to live on domain such as : www.mydomain.com.

[image: Form email body using contact form 7 plugin]

My confusion is where i'm wrong or what's the mistake. I'm using latest wordpress 4.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When your site goes live, you have to reset all the settings of contact form 7, like whne you are going to your site live then you have to do the themes settings again, same with the contact form 7.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry webtuts4u. Its not at all your mistake. Its a fact that when you move your site to live, the options will be reset. So you have to fill your options again into the live site. This solves your problem.